# Is there a way to reset the Personal Identification Number (PIN) Try Counter? (Tag 0x9F17)

Tags: smartcard, emv

I'm writing a terminal application, and after many tests.. The try counter reached zero. Now VERIFY commands are not being sent. I was wondering if there was a way to reset this counter.

Answer (score 0):

If the access rules are set up accordingly to allow them, the commands *Reset Retry Counter* or *Change Reference Data* will reset the error counter to its maximum beyond optionally establishing a new PIN value. (Successful Verify would also achieve that, but is not available in your situation.)

For details, as usual, see ISO 7816 part 4 and the manual of your card operating system.

Answer (score 0):

for the terminal application (POS) if the card counter is needed for reset it should be using issuer script not
other wise it should go with online Pin the  response contain issuer script from issuer to reset the counter